# CSV to Mysql insert datetime

Tags: php, mysql, csv, datetime

I have CSV file and i want insert CSV rows to Mysql database. 
When I inserting "23.05.17 17:53:25" to DB from CSV in column START DATE(format Datetime), I am getting 2023-25-17 17:53:25.

How i can convert that, which on DB get correctly date format 2017-05-23 17:53:25

T`hanks

Comment: From @eskeli answer -> `$ins="INSERT INTO stugayc (CHECKID,CHECKSTDATE,CHECKENDDATE ) VALUES(" . $row[0] . ", STR_TO_DATE(" . $row[1] . ", '%d.%m.%y %H:%i:%s'),'" . $row[2] . "')";` this will work

Comment: you can use `STR_TO_DATE() `

Answer (score 1):

It might not be an orthodox solution, but you could simply parse the input string and recreate the datetime in the format mysql expects.

```
// for each line in the csv
list($datePart, $timePart) = explode(' ', $fields['date']);
list($d, $m, $y) = explode('.', $datePart);
$dbDate = "$y-$m-$d $timePart";
```

It would be better to add some input validation, but if what you're doing is a data import script it's ok.

Comment: I try, but i get that
 
0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You should use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) mysql function:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('23.05.17 17:53:25', '%d.%m.%y %H:%i:%s');
```

Result:

> 2017-05-23 17:53:25

You can even use the compact form of time fields `%T`:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('23.05.17 17:53:25', '%d.%m.%y %T');
```

Result:

> 2017-05-23 17:53:25

Comment: This is my insert code

 $ins="INSERT INTO `stugayc` (`CHECKID`,`CHECKSTDATE`,`CHECKENDDATE`
        )
VALUES('$row[0]','STR_TO_DATE('$row[1]', '%d.%m.%y %H:%i:%s')','$row[2]' )";

Comment: You should consider using [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection but for what I see it should work as expected.

Comment: I can not do it ))

Comment: I was wrong, you have to remove quote from the `STR_TO_DATE` function like so: `$ins="INSERT INTO stugayc (CHECKID,CHECKSTDATE,CHECKENDDATE ) VALUES('$row[0]',STR_TO_DATE('$row[1]', '%d.%m.%y %H:%i:%s'),'$row[2]' )";`.

Comment: Excuse me can I check csv file value?

Example if($row=='2017-05-23 17:53:25')
$row='';