# Not enough arguments for format string when running script

Tags: python

Here is the script that I am running:

```
#Connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost:3306", user = "username", passwd = "password", db = "database", port = 3306)
cursor = db.cursor()
csv_data = csv.reader(file('/home/pi/z_fs/sample_file_for_mysql_upload.csv'))

next(csv_data, None)

for row in csv_data:
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO z_rec_sales(id,address,state,city,zipcode,price,sold_date,price_per_sqft, beds,bathrooms,sqft,url)' \
          'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s","%s", "%s", "%s", "%s","%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")',row)
```

When I run this script, I get an error:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I apologize.  I just filled it out.

Comment: My advice is to debug `row`: print it to console and see what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

The number of %s specifier doesn't matches number of arguments you are passing.
You have 12 arguments, but only 11 '%s'.

Comment: I added the additional %s, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe the rows in file don't have 12 values for the 12 arguments. Check it please!

Comment: I thought about that.  The id field is an auto increment primary key field in the database.  The column in the csv file is blank.

Comment: Ok, I think you have in row a empty field for ID, so you can add a new column on your table to store these values, like "aux_ID tinytext null default null". Switch the "ID" column of your code for "aux_ID" column, like this:
`'INSERT INTO z_rec_sales(aux_ID,address,state,city,zipcode,price,sold_date,price_per_sqft, beds,bathrooms,sqft,url)' \
      'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s","%s", "%s", "%s", "%s","%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")'`.

So, after run your script you can remove aux_ID.

Comment: I did what you said and I also changed all of the fields that has numbers in it to varchar since I won't be doing any calculations in MySQL.  The script ran, but what is interesting is that it added a record that has %s in every field except the date field which reads 0000-00-00.

Comment: Maybe the format of the date field in your file is different the table (yyyy-mm-dd). So you can use STR_TO_DATE to format your date. [Check this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174090/csv-to-mysql-insert-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO z_rec_sales(id,address,state,city,zipcode,price,sold_date,price_per_sqft, beds,bathrooms,sqft,url)' \
'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s","%s", "%s", "%s", "%s","%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")',row)
```

Number of %s specifier doesn't matches number of arguments you are passing.

Comment: I added the additional %s, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please check if row has 12 arguments.

Comment: since id is auto field.Can you try by removing it from Insert string and have only 11 %s.